# Python script not running due to a missing argument

Tags: python, python-2.7, github, amazon-s3, boto

Python beginner. I am trying to run the following script (download_meta_review_dump.py). To make it easier to view I have included a link to github, as I had issues copying it here - https://github.com/trustyou/example-meta-review-dump

I am using Python 2.7.13 on Windows 10 and receive the following error when I try running the script:

`Demonstration of how to download a complete meta-review API dump.
[-h] --dest_folder DEST_FOLDER 
Demonstration of how to download a complete meta-review API dump.
: error: argument --dest_folder is required`

What I am expecting is a prompt to appear, requesting me to enter an AWS access key.

awscli and boto have already been installed.

Also I have created an empty folder (named dest_folder) in the same folder where i have saved the script, but still receive the above error.

Can anyone point me in the right direction of what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Well, are you passing that argument? Please show exactly how you are running that script.

Comment: You aren't specifying dest-folder when you run the script.  Note that dest-folder is a REQUIRED parameter.

Comment: Running the script as it appears on github. No change has been made.

Comment: @AnthonyS *how exactly* are you running the script? This is very important.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga open command prompt and enter the following - C:\Users\anstylianou\Documents\Projects\TrustYou\meta-review-dump> python download_meta_review_dump.py

Comment: Right, so, you are not providing the argument after all. Use `python download_meta_review_dump.py --dest_folder <foldername>`

Comment: Thanks! managed to get the prompt for the AWS access key, but for some reason when i try to type it no text appears in the command prompt. Cursor doesnt even move. I can only press enter.

Comment: That is probably to keep your access key hidden (like when entering a sudo password). Just type your key and hit enter, should work.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to download without pointing a destination. Create the destination folder(let's call it `container`) inside the folder of the script and append this to the end of the script call `~script name here~ --dest_folder container` or `~script name here~ --dest_folder "container"`.